# UNIX_TIMESTAMP() comparison

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Hello everyone I've a problem with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`: when I'm using it to check it against another `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` I never get the result I expect.

Here a small query as example:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%Y%m%d')) as Date1,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate2, '%Y%m%d')) as Date2
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN Date1 and Date2 )
```

Where `Date1` as `1387062000` as value and `Date2` is `1389740400`, and unless we are after Jan 2014 the result from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is between the 2 values.

Still it gives me no results when I should be getting at least 1 row from the table; I've tried to format the date before feeding it to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` but I've failed in every try.

Probably is something really stupid but I've been bashing my head on this for over 2 hours without getting any result.

Anyone got any idea where the error could be located?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of `Date1` and `Date2`?

Comment: It is not relevant, I convert the value with `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: It *is* relevant. If the type isn't a character type and the conversion isn't possible, you will get `NULL` and the comparison will fail.

Comment: The query above is an example as I stated, I take the necessary steps to ensure the data I'm using is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom aliases are not filtered by `WHERE` clause you need to use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%Y%m%d')) as Date1,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate2, '%Y%m%d')) as Date2
FROM
  my_table
HAVING
  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN Date1 and Date2 )
```

or

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%Y%m%d')) as Date1,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate2, '%Y%m%d')) as Date2
FROM
  my_table
WHERE 
  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%Y%m%d'))
  and 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(mydate2, '%Y%m%d')))
```

Comment: I alway forget about `HAVING`, can't say thank you enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do the other way round?

```
SELECT @TODAY := SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d');

SELECT ... FROM my_table WHERE @TODAY BETWEEN (mydate, mydate2);
```

This way you can also visually inspect `@TODAY` as well as `mydate` and `mydate2` on the target row, and can use indexing on the date fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the columns or use MySQL's @variables, thank you for your approach, I'll keep it in mind the next time I need something similar :-)